# From Smarty 3 to Twig 2, how occurences of a template are managed?

Tags: caching, twig, smarty

I use Smarty 3 in several websites and I am reviewing how twig works.
There is one thing I don't understand with Twig compared to Smarty, How occurrences of a same template are managed.

In Smarty, first you create your template cache with a template name and a cache ID for your specific page for this template

```
$template = $smarty->createTemplate('article.tpl', 'article|12');
```

This will create a cached page.

To render the result in Smarty you first test if the page exists in cache and then render it else access to the database to retrieve data a&nd assign variables.

```
if (!$template->isCached()) {
   // access to the database
   // assign variables
}
```

Then the page is rendered

```
$tpl->display();
```

But in Twig I just see

```
$loader = new \Twig\Loader\FilesystemLoader('/path/to/templates');
$twig = new \Twig\Environment($loader, ['cache' => 
    '/path/to/compilation_cache']);
$template = $twig->load('index.html');
echo $template->render(['the' => 'variables', 'go' => 'here']);
```

What is the equivalent of "!$template->isCached()" to avoid access to the database each time?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't one. Twig does not cache rendered HTML output on its own. It only caches the result of template compilation into PHP code, which is still executed every time you render the template.

You will need a reverse proxy in front of your application, or some kind of database caching layer to avoid repeated calls to your app.